# Can't manage CSS in Android Studio

Tags: css, android-studio

I've recently started working with **Android Studio**.
I've imported a project that was built using **Eclipse** and manged to handle all the import. Still, there's one line that I can't get to work:

```
     NativeCSS.styleWithCSS("MainCss.css",css, RemoteContentRefreshPeriod.Never);
```

All the text within the brackets is marked with a red under-line.

Thank you for helping me!

**Update**: I've alredy imported the `nativeCSS.jar`!

Comment: By the way, I've alredy imported the nativeCSS.jar

Comment: If something is "marked with a red under-line" it should tell you what the problem is if you hover over the text. What does the tooltip say the problem is when you do that?

Comment: cannot resolve method 'styleWithCss(Java.lang.String, Java.net.URL, com.nativecss.enum.RemoteContentRefreshPeriod)

Comment: So it can't find a method. That means either that method does not exist, or the jar with that method is not on your classpath correctly.

Comment: ...or that the class has not been correctly imported